# will paginate problem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate plugin in rails project

My problem is the next I have `Product` model.so In index view I list all products.
This view has got filters options which obviously filter and update the page via AJAX.

NOTE 1: The filters are link_to_remote to action `filters`.then processes the order and then update the view.

My problem is that I paginate the product in `index` action and then I should paginate again in `filters` action. So how could replace or transform the page links to remote links to `filters` action.

Excuse my english syntax and thanks in advance.

NOTE 2: If you need my code then I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of the way you are updating the list of products with Ajax but if your method `filters` render a view or partial, you might include the pagination in this partial and update it with the list of products.

Comment: Thanks. However when the partial replace old pagination links go to filter?authentication_key?more_parameters

Comment: I need replace the link_to (pagination links) with link_to_remote.

Comment: To use will_paginate with ajax, see [the wiki page on the doc](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Ajax-pagination). I'm not sure to understand you other comment ? If you are using Rails 3 I would also suggest you to switch to [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) which is I think the new "default" for paginate with rails